# Why creating an instance without reference is enough in the server of asynchat?

Tags: python

I am reading the post (http://pymotw.com/2/asynchat/#module-asynchat) on how  to use module asynchat. Here is the code for server

```
import asyncore
import logging
import socket

from asynchat_echo_handler import EchoHandler

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    """Receives connections and establishes handlers for each client.
    """

    def __init__(self, address):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind(address)
        self.address = self.socket.getsockname()
        self.listen(1)
        return

    def handle_accept(self):
        # Called when a client connects to our socket
        client_info = self.accept()
        EchoHandler(sock=client_info[0])
        # We only want to deal with one client at a time,
        # so close as soon as we set up the handler.
        # Normally you would not do this and the server
        # would run forever or until it received instructions
        # to stop.
        self.handle_close()
        return

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
```

Why "EchoHandler(sock=client_info[0])" is enough? The object created does not have a name. How to call the method defined in the object of EchoHandler ?

Comment: Why not just `eh = EchoHandler(sock=client_info[0]); eh.somemethod()`

Answer (score 0):

"EchoHandler(sock=client_info[0])" is enough because no method call to it  is needed in this example. You just connect the handler to the client and forget about it. It will answer the calls from the client itself and closes when the client closes.
When you want to call it later just do it like jedwards wrote.